# What does < in Shell Scripts do?

Tags: bash, shell

For example,

```
matlab -nodesktop -singleCompThread < run%d/run.m
```

I know it means matlab is suppose to use the run.m file in the run%d directory but what does it mean for shells in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By itself, *command* `<` *filename* tells the shell to run the named *command* with its input coming from the file *filename*, instead of from the terminal where you typed the command line.

You can go the other way, too, sending the output of the command into a file, with *command* `>` *filename*.

There are actually two different output streams connected to the terminal - the normal one, which is called "standard output" and redirected by `>`, and the "standard error" stream, which lets the program tell you when something went wrong even though its normal output is going into a file instead of your terminal.  If you really don't want to see those error messages, but want them to go into the terminal as well, you can use `>&` *filename*.

If you want to send the errors into their own separate file, you can use `2>`*error_filename*; that leaves the standard output stream alone, going to your terminal or wherever you sent it with `>` or `|`.

There's a lot more you can do, like use the output of one command as a file anywhere another command expects a filename.  See [the link konsolebox posted](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for more details.

Answer (score 6):

See the bash manual about redirections: http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Answer (score 1):

it changes the input of the command from the keyboard to that file

Answer (score 0):

It's roughly equivalent to

```
cat run%d/run.m | matlab -nodesktop -singleCompThread
```

There are probably some subtle differences I'm not aware of. But it's basically sending the content of `run%d/run.m` to `matlab` as "keyboard" input (via standard input).